# Unable to get blob for OpenAI generated image

Tags: react-native, cors, fetch, blob

I'm creating a React Native app that allows users to generate images using AI. Since the URL that the API returns is only valid for one hour, I need a way to upload it to Supabase Storage. The only solution I found was to get the blob by fetching and then upload that. Below is the code I'm trying and the error I get. I believe this is an issue with OpenAI not allowing the request but I'm not sure.

```
            const fileName = `${Date.now()}-${Math.floor(
              Math.random() * 100000
            )}.png`;
            const imageResponse = await fetch(url);
            const blobFile = await imageResponse.blob();

            console.log("Uploading image...");
            const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
              .from("public/posts")
              .upload(fileName, blobFile);

            if (error) {
              throw new Error(`Failed to upload image: ${error.message}`);
            }
```

`Origin http://localhost:19006 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200`

Answer (score 1):

One of your backends is not allowing cross origin requests (CORS). This can not be fixed by frontend code and needs to be configured on your server.

[how to do it with supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/cors)

If you can not solve this issue by configuring your servers, you can add another backend in the middle, that would act as a proxy and have proper CORS rules setup.